# how to add attachment(text file) to database mail?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have scenario

Daily i run a sql job to apply a new updates to one table - this job will create one text file daily - text file contains all new updates

I can send a mail to client that job is successfully completed - now i need to send him a text file as a attachment

Is there any way to send attachment through GUI (SQL Server Job setting)

I cann't run the script

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
```

I googled for this scenario but no information from GUI END - i could find from only with scripts

Comment: Is it due to permissions that you cannot use EXEC sp_send_dbmail?

Comment: Yes and with the running same job i need to send mail  confirmation and attachment

Comment: There is no way to send attachment through GUI. If you dont have permissions to execute the sp_send_dbmail then you have to ask your DBA or sysadmin to grant you that permission.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking of for the same issue myself, and gave up. It seems that attachments can only be sent using TSQL, such as this

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='MailProfile',
  @recipients='me@gmail.com',
  @subject='TestEmail',
  @body='I'm sending you this document...',
  @file_attachments='D:\TEST\file.doc'
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer ,I know it can be done through scripts but i cann't use  "EXEC sp_send_dbmail "

Comment: @CarolBakerWest -- the script will throw syntax error as the '@body' should have 2 quotes  ==>   @body='I''m sending you this document...'